# Laravel-Elixir: How to define file depencencies in gulpfile.js?

Tags: laravel, dependencies, gulp, watch, laravel-elixir

My gulpfile.js contains this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less(['frontend.less','bootstrap.less','variables.less'],'public/css/frontend.css');
});
```

frontend.less contains:

```
@import 'bootstrap.less';
```

bootstrap.less contains:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/less/normalize.less";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/less/print.less";
...
```

Well, the frontend.css depends on

- frontend.less
- bootstrap.less
- variables.less

When I start "gulp watch", it recompiles the frontend.css only when I modify frontend.less, but it should start, too, when I modify one of these files.

I need to define dependencies, but how?